# How to decide what database configuration should be built for various applications like OLTP, Reporting, High Availability, etc in sybase ASE

Tags: sap-ase, sap-iq

I am trying to figure out how to set up different labs configurations for Sybase ASE depending upon the applications for which it's going to be used like OLTP, OLAP, Reporting or High Availability.

I am okay to involve using the Sybase IQ, Sybase Replication if there is a need.

Could anyone have any vision or way to explore it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should search in sybase technical white papers.
F.e.

HA -

Managing Workloads with ASE: Techniques for OLTP Scaling and Performance Management with Large SMP and Shared Disk Clusters
http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1091630

Sybase CEP High Availability
http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1086848

DWH and REP

Sybase Replication Server Real — Time Loading into Sybase IQ
http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1089003